# Attribution attribute on amp-social-share for Facebook doesn't seem to work

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to implement AMP, and when I go to /url.html#development=1 the Facebook amp-social-share node errors saying "attribution is required". But I have an attribution attribute on that node and it's a valid Facebook AppID.

```
<amp-social-share type="facebook" attribution="[FBAppID]" width="60" height="44"></amp-social-share>
```

Why might that amp-social-share node fail and the other three work?

I also have this in the `<head>` even tho I'm not sure it's necessary:

```
<script async="async" custom-element="amp-social-share" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-social-share-0.1.js"></script>
```

Is this something that is still under construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using the attribute attribution, rather than data-attribution.

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-social-share/amp-social-share.md#simple-examples

This example shows specifying attribution as an element attribute.

Comment: I was using this page, and I swear it had just attribution="12344" and none of the HTML5 data-... stuff before, but now it shows what you've referenced. https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-social-share.html I'll use the github version of the docs as a reference from now on just to be safe. Thanks again!